# ZF2 nested data validation

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-inputfilter, zend-form-fieldset

I'm trying make to work my validation. I have data posted to controller in the format like this:

```
[
    'property' => 'value',
    'nested_property' => [
        'property' => 'value',
        // ...
    ]
]
```

I have divided fields/filters and form into different classes and just gather it together in the Form's controller that looks like that:

```
public function __construct($name, $options)
{
    // ...
    $this->add(new SomeFieldset($name, $options));
    $this->setInputFilter(new SomeInputFilter());
}
```

But it doesn't work properly, looks like it just ignores nested array (or ignores everything). What have I missed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up your inputfilter like the way you've setup your forms including the fieldsets if you use the `InputFilter` class.

So when you've got a structure like:

1. MyForm 
   1.1 NestedFieldset
   1.2 AnotherFieldset

Your inputfilters need to have the same structure:

1. MyFormInputFilter
   1.1 NestedFielsetInputFilter
   1.2 AnotherFieldsetInputFilter

Some example code:

```php
class ExampleForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name, $options)
    {
        // handle the dependencies
        parent::__construct($name, $options);

        $this->setInputFilter(new ExampleInputFilter());
    }

    public function init()
    {
        // some fields within your form

        $this->add(new SomeFieldset('SomeFieldset'));
    }
}

class SomeFieldset extends Fieldset
{
    public function __construct($name = null, array $options = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $options);
    }

    public function init()
    {
        // some fields
    }
}

class ExampleInputFilter extends InputFilter
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // configure your validation for your form

        $this->add(new SomeFieldsetInputFilter(), 'SomeFieldset');
    }
}

class SomeFieldsetInputFilter extends InputFilter
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // configure your validation for your SomeFieldset
    }
}
```

So the important part of configuring your inputFilter for these situations is that you need to reuse the name of your fieldset when using: `$this->add($input, $name = null)` within your `InputFilter` classes.